# Tcl and Ctrl-C in Windows console

Tags: windows, tcl, interrupt, windows-console

I have a problem intercepting Ctrl-C in my Windows Tcl 8.5 application. I have added a console handler in an extension library I develop, but it's not always working.

If some Tcl code is executing, then everything is OK. But if the application is waiting for user input, pressing Ctrl-C terminates it. My handler is called, but at the same time (in a different thread?) the Tcl REPL calls `Tcl_Exit`. This really messes up everything.

As far as I can tell, REPL calls `Tcl_Exit` is called because it erroneously thinks that `stdin` has encountered `EOF`. This, in turn, is caused by the fact that when Ctrl-C is pressed, the read routine returns, and it returns the number of bytes read, which is zero. REPL interprets this condition as EOF.

Is there an easy way to fix this problem? I know I could ditch the Tcl built-in channel and supply my own, but this seems an overkill for this simple problem.

I have tried `twapi::set_console_control_handler` but it doesn't seem to work at all. Pressing Ctrl-C always terminates the application, and the handler is never called.

Comment: I tried a quick critcl built extension to call SetConsoleCtrlHandler and get the same effect. The handler function is called but tclsh exits anyway. I suspect in the twapi version it raises an event to run the script and exits before the event is processed, hence fails to call the script. The C handler probably is getting called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx) points out that CTRL_C handling is handled separately but this can be disabled by setting the console mode to `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT`. This then reports Ctrl-C events as keyboard input.

The following critcl code loaded into an interpreter (using `load ctrl_c.dll ctrl_c; win32::SetCtrlHandler` lets me intercept the Control-C keyboard input without exiting:

```
package require critcl

namespace eval win32 {
    critcl::ccode {
#define STRICT
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
#include <windows.h>

BOOL CtrlHandler(DWORD dwEvent)
{
    switch (dwEvent)
    {
        case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        fprintf(stderr, "ctrl_c\n");
        return TRUE;
        default:
        return FALSE;
    }
}
}

    # Quick and dirty test CTRL_C interception in windows.
    critcl::cproc SetCtrlHandler {} ok {
        BOOL b = SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
        if (b)
           b = SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE)CtrlHandler, TRUE);
        return b ? TCL_OK : TCL_ERROR;
    }
}
```

Compiled using `critcl -lib ctrl_c.tcl`.

However! Once a Ctrl-C has been seen, the console input no longer echos anything typed by the user. It does read the input and acts upon it but does not echo that input. As an example session:

```
% load ctrl_c.dll ctrl_c
% win32::SetCtrlHandler
% ctrl_c
8.6.1
% -blocking 1 -buffering line -buffersize 4096 -encoding unicode -eofchar → -translation auto
% -blocking 1 -buffering line -buffersize 4096 -encoding unicode -eofchar {} -translation crlf
%
```

What is not shown is where I entered `fconfigure stdin` and `fconfigure stdout`. Hopefully this can assist your search for a solution.

Comment: It looks like setting `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT` is like setting raw/noecho mode on a Unix terminal. Might it be enough to reset it in a few microseconds using a timer event? I don't know really…

Answer (score 2):

Regarding twapi::set_console_control_handler, it requires the event loop to be running to be effective. The thread handling the Ctrl-C will continue with the default OS provided handler if the Tcl thread does not respond within 100ms. Perhaps this should be changed to default to NOT passing on to the OS handler if no response is received.

Comment: Added an RFE to change Tcl http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/tktview/e66e44444023ee253956979c54c905c6006f4540

Comment: Updated Tcl trunk (post-8.6.4) to not treat the Ctrl-C as EOF on console.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I just downloaded the latest release and Ctrl-C doesn't instantly kill my program any more.